# ¿Cómo agregar método put y delete?

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs

Tengo esta aplicación hecha en nodejs. Necesito agregar el método put pero no me deja y no se donde está el error

1. Aqui el código del ruter:

```js
router.get("/post/:title", function(req, res){
    var query = {"title" : req.params.title};
    post.findOne(query, function(err, posts){
        res.render("admin/posts/posts", {posts : posts});
    });
});

router.put('/post/:title', function(req, res) {
  var query = {"title": req.params.title};
  var update = {title: req.body.title, body : req.body.post, created_at : req.body.date, autor: req.body.autor};
  var options = {new: true};
  post.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function(err, posts){
    console.log(posts)
    res.render(
      'admin/posts/post',
      {title : 'posts - ' + posts.pregunta, posts : posts}
    );
  });
});

router.delete('/post/:title', function(req, res) {
  var query = {"title": req.params.title};
  post.findOneAndRemove(query, function(err, posts){
    console.log(posts)
    res.redirect('/admin/posts/');
  });
});
```

2.codigo de la vista hbs

```html
<form  method="post" action="/admin/post/{{posts.title}}?_method=PUT">
    titulo
    <input type="text" name="title" value="{{posts.title}}">
    entrada
    <input type="text" name="body" value="{{posts.post}}">
    fecha
    <input type="date" name="date" value="{{posts.created_at}}">
    autor
    <input type="text" name="autor" value="{{posts.autor}}">
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
<form method="post" action="/admin/post/{{posts.title}}?_method=DELETE">
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lamentablemente `put` y `delete` no son estándares en HTML, aun si envías el parametro `_method` este sera tratado como parámetro en la url, mas no como un convertidor de métodos.

Muchos frameworks utilizan campos ocultos para especificar el tipo de método que desean utilizar (cosa que tampoco es estandar):

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
</form>
```

Ya que estas utilizando `Node.js` te recomiendo utilizar un middleware, que precisamente hace esto que te comento arriba

https://github.com/expressjs/method-override

Este middleware sobrescribe el método enviándolo dentro del formulario como campo oculto para adaptarlo a la configuración de tu router

Answer (score -1):

Según el estándar de HTML, GET y POST són los únicos valores posibles en el atributo "method".

Si cambias el código de NodeJS a :

```
router.post('/post/:title', function(req, res) { ...
```

debería functionarte con el tag de formulario:

```
<form method="post" ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Según yo lo veo, deberías cambiar en el form por `<form method="put" y <form method="delete"` estás haciendo `post` en todos tus formularios.